# If $(f,g) \in R$ then $( (f \circ f),(g \circ g) )\in R$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I was doing the exercise nº 17-(b) on chapter 5.3 from the book "How To Prove It" by D.J. Velleman and I got stuck. The exercise is as follows:

Suppose $A$ is a set, and let $F = \{ f | f: A \rightarrow A \}$ and $P = \{ f \in F | f \text{ is one-to-one and onto } \}$. Define a relation $R$ on $F$ as follows:

$R = \{ (f,g) \in F \times F | \exists h \in P (f = h^{-1} \circ g \circ h ) \}$.

Prove that if $(f,g) \in R$ then $((f \circ f), (g \circ g)) \in R$.

As I understand it, we know that $R(f) = g$ and we are asked to prove that $R(f \circ f) = R(h^{-1} \circ g \circ g \circ h) = g \circ g$.

I'm having an hard time ending this proof.

Comment: $R$ is a binary relation, not a function. $R(f)=g$ means nothing. You have to prove that if $\exists h\in P\quad f=h^{-1}\circ g\circ h$ then $\exists k\in P\quad f\circ f=k^{-1}\circ g\circ g\circ k$.

Comment: Right... it looks like the same $h$ that qualifies $(f,g)$ for the relation can be used to qualify $(f\circ f, g \circ g)$ for it.

Comment: $R$ is a relation, not a function. $R(f) = g$ looks as though there's exactly one $g$ related to $f$, but we could have $f\, R\, g_1$ and $f\, R\, g_2$ with $g_1 \neq g_2$.

Comment: the notation is unusual, but we can make it mean something. I would write $fRg$ and $(f\circ f)R(g\circ g)$, but that is only my preference.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't understand your first comment

Comment: After "You have to prove"

Comment: I juste rewrote "Prove that if $(f,g) \in R$ then $((f \circ f), (g \circ g)) \in R$", using the definition of $R$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, what I'm trying to prove here doesn't make much sense.

What I'm actually asked to prove is:

"Prove that if $(f,g) \in R$ then $((f \circ f), (g \circ g) ) \in R$".

We can see that if $(f,g) \in R$ then $\exists h \in P$ such that $(f = h^{-1} \circ g \circ h)$ and thus $f \circ f = (h^{-1} \circ g \circ h) \circ (h^{-1} \circ g \circ h) = (h^{-1} \circ g \circ g \circ h)$. Since $f \circ f \in F$ we can conclude that $((f \circ f), (g \circ g) ) \in R$

Comment: +1. Thumbs up ! You may accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

$ (f,g) \in R  \rightarrow \exists h \in P : f = h^{-1} \circ g \circ h $.

The same $h$ will work as it is mentioned in the comments.

$h^{-1} \circ (g \circ g) \circ h =
h^{-1} \circ (g \circ h \circ h^{-1} \circ g) \circ h =
(h^{-1} \circ g \circ h) \circ (h^{-1} \circ g \circ h) =  f \circ f$

Therefore

$ ((f \circ f), (g \circ g)) \in R$.